# ASP.NET Core Migration from 2.1 -> 2.2 Issue with dependencies in Azure deployment

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment, asp.net-core-2.2

I am having Kudu issues while deploying a ASP.NET Core 2.2 app to Azure. The application was migrated from 2.1 -> 2.2 and deployed just fine before the upgrade.

I have used this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) as reference

Deployment Error Log:

```
    Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.
  Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\Source\PlanetDiego.Core\PlanetDiego.Core.csproj...
D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\2.2.100\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Could not find file 'D:\home\.nuget\newtonsoft.json\6.0.4\newtonsoft.json.6.0.4.nupkg'. [D:\home\site\repository\Source\PlanetDiego.sln]
Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet restore "D:\home\site\repository\Source\PlanetDiego.sln"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\79.11121.3655\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

Interestingly every deployment attempt returns a different erroneous dependency error:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.
  Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\Source\PlanetDiego.Core\PlanetDiego.Core.csproj...
D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\2.2.100\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Could not find file 'D:\home\.nuget\awssdk.core\3.3.0\awssdk.core.3.3.0.nupkg'. [D:\home\site\repository\Source\PlanetDiego.sln]
Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet restore "D:\home\site\repository\Source\PlanetDiego.sln"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\79.11121.3655\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

csproj  file. As you can see, there is no dependency on newtonsoft.json.6.0.4.nupkg or awssdk.core.3.3.0.nupkg. The version specified is 12.0.1 and 3.3.29, respectively.
I tried going to the Kudu Console in Azure and deleting deploy.cmd and deploymentCacheKey in the D:\home\site\deployments\tools folder. Unfortunately no effect.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>PlanetDiego.Core</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>PlanetDiego.Core</PackageId>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Core" Version="3.3.29.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.3.31" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.SimpleEmail" Version="3.3.7.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="TweetinviAPI" Version="4.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: It appears someone stumbled upon the same problem. https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2914

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the `D:\home\.nuget\` directory and then re-running the restore/deployment.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! That successfully remapped to the right packages. I also had to run it as an Outofprocess <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel> in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was able to deploy the app with target framework 2.1 and Azure Tools extension in the Visual Studio Code. `dotnet publish -c Relase`, then right click `bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/publish` folder and Deploy To Web App.

The SDK 2.2 is [new](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/12/04/asp-net-core-2-2-available-today/), maybe it is broken on Azure now.

Comment: Yes, I have deployed several 2.1 application on Azure without a problem. The 2.2 SDK is officially supported on Azure since 12/6 I believe. However, when deploying via Githib or Bitbucket the package restore fails.

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem. So, I suggest that you could go to [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=&type=&language=) to open an issue to check if the sdk has problem?

Comment: See comment on my original post. There appears to be an open ticket already. Thanks.